# about spring applicationContext

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

i learned that when spring applicationContext is created,
context itself will be registered as bean.
so i made a simple code and expect applicationContext as a bean.
However, when i create applicationContext with java-code like below,
i couldn't see applicationContext as a bean..
====code====
ApplicationContext parent = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(basePath + "parentContext.xml");

```
    GenericApplicationContext child = new GenericApplicationContext(parent);
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(child);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(basePath+"childContext.xml");
    child.refresh();
    
    Printer printer = child.getBean("printer",Printer.class);
    assertNotNull(printer);
    
    for(String bean : parent.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.out.println("TTTT : "+ bean +" : "+parent.getBean(bean).getClass().getName());
    }
```

=====================
i both tried with parent and child. could anyone can explain why applicationContext itself is not
registered as a bean?

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding this line to parentContext.xml:

```
<import resource="contextSub.xml"/>
```

and in the java code add this annotation

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    ApplicationContext parent = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(basePath + "parentContext.xml");
    GenericApplicationContext child = new GenericApplicationContext(parent);
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(child);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(basePath+"childContext.xml");
    child.refresh();

    Printer printer = child.getBean("printer",Printer.class);
    assertNotNull(printer);

    for(String bean : parent.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
    System.out.println("TTTT : "+ bean +" : "+parent.getBean(bean).getClass().getName());
}
```

Let me know if this helps.